# On SQL indexes: how many distinct values are too many? number of indexes irrelevant for SELECT-only table?

Tags: sql, indexing, database-performance

I'm an SQL newbie, but here's what I've gathered so far regarding indexes:

1. Indexing on a column with too many different values may be counterproductive as it'll take longer traversing the index and retrieving a few records at a time instead of doing it straight from the table.
2. Pathological cases such as (1) aside, indexes always improve the speed of SELECT statements at the cost of slower INSERT, UPDATE, etc.

My questions are:

- Is (1) true, and if so, how many distinct values are "too many"? I'm considering indexing on two age columns that together have 139 different values (1-99, 'years'; 1-11, 'months'; 1-29, 'days') on a table with >100M records. Do I stand to gain a lot here?
- If (2) is true, and my table won't be updated ever again, does this mean I can have several indexes on it and this will never hinder my SELECT queries?

Comment: (1) is false.  (2) I would not describe those cases as "pathological".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's probably that the opposite is true. A column with few distinct values is not a good candidate for an index. Generally an optimizer will evaluate the cost of using an index, vs the cost of a full scan. The optimizer will then choose the access with the lowest cost
2. If you do not ever update a table, then index should not really be a penalty, except for maybe disk space. However, just because an index is present, does not necessarily mean it will be used; as per 1 above.